# Integrating comments of a Facebook post with Facebook Comments Box of a webpage

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-comments

I would like to know if anyone knows any app|plugin|way that I can connect the comments under a specific post in fb with fb-comment-plugin under a specific webpage. 
For example anyone who comments on a webpage with facebook comments plugin becomes visible under a specific post in a fb page and vise versa.

Comment: which platform you are using? are you using FB php sdk or else what? brief your question for the better answer

Comment: My platform is .Net. Do you need any other information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, the Comments Plugin can´t show the comments of a page post (or album/photo/whatever) on facebook. You can also try this in the Plugin Configurator: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

You have to connect a specific URL to the Plugin, but it does not work with a facebook.com URL. Nothing will be shown.